# Horizontal text alignment in captions for subfigures

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, subfloats

Captions in subfigures are justified by default, which does not always look pretty:

[image: figure/subfigure caption alignment]

```
\documentclass[]{tGIS2e} % http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/tgislatex.zip

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
%\raggedright
\subfigure[caption for a]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_a}%
}
~
\subfigure[capture for b, justified]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_b}%
}
~
\subfigure[justification becomes ugly sometimes]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_c}%
}
~
\subfigure[there should be a way of applying \textbackslash raggedright or a similar command ]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_d}%
}
\caption{Figure example}%
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How would it be possible to keep the overall alignment of the image and its caption, and make the subcaption aligned, let’s say left?  Adding `\raggedright` does not help — it shifts the whole image left, but keeps the alignment of the text.

It would be good if the solution exited for the markup given above, because the template I’m using does not support `subfigure` as environment and also conflicts with `subcaption` package.

Comment: It is not clear, do you want all the captions `\raggedright` or are you merely asking for caption `(a)` to be left-aligned?  Or both?

Comment: Ideally I want to control the alignment of every caption, but if not, simply making all captions aligned left would be enough. I pretty much dislike unnecessarily large spaces between words, it frequently happens when text is justified. This slows down reading.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that we can see which package or documentclass is defining your `\subfigure` command.

Comment: @AndrewSwann, done. Sorry for forgetting to include documentclass into my example.

Comment: You can use tabular instead of subfigure.  A multiline caption can be implemented using a p{} field, or putting a \parbox inside a c field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your documentclass is loading the (obsolete) `subfigure` package.  This package has options such as `raggedright` for the caption justification.  These options can be turned on locally by issuing e.g. `\subcapraggedrighttrue`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[]{tGIS2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\subcapraggedrighttrue
\subfigure[caption for a]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_a}%
}
~
\subfigure[capture for b, justified]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_b}%
}
~
\subfigure[justification becomes ugly sometimes]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_c}%
}
~
\subfigure[there should be a way of applying \textbackslash raggedright or a similar command ]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_d}%
}
\caption{Figure example}%
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\subcapcentertrue
\subfigure[caption for a]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_a}%
}
~
\subfigure[capture for b, justified]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_b}%
}
~
\subfigure[justification becomes ugly sometimes]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_c}%
}
~
\subfigure[there should be a way of applying \textbackslash raggedright or a similar command ]{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}%
    \label{fig:myfig_d}%
}
\caption{Figure example}%
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The list of possible commands includes

- `\subcapraggedrighttrue`
- `\subcapcentertrue`
- `\subcapcenterlasttrue`

There are also `false` variants.

Similarly there is `\subcaphangtrue` to make sure the label sticks out to the left of the caption block.  For example, in the above example

```
\subcapraggedrighttrue
\subcaphangtrue
```

give

[image: Sample hang output]

Also the `nooneline` option corresponds to `\subcapnoonelinetrue`.  See the `Declaration of Options` section of the [`subfigure` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure), where you will as be able to deduce how to place captions above, rather than below the figures, etc.

Comment: This works great! By the way, are there any options to make all caption text appear on the right from the label (a, b, c) like in the answer by @steven-b-segletes, but without a need to define the width manually?

Comment: @AlexanderKachkaev Sure.  Explanation added.

Comment: do you know by a chance what command in subcaption+floatrow packages does the same as \subcaphangtrue in subfigure?

Comment: @AndrewSwann could you please also take a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564508/figures-not-appearing-horizontally-in-two-columned-latex-journal)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the captions being offset relative to the `(a)`, `(b)`, ... labels and don't mind specifying the caption width, then this could work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\textwidth 6in
\newcommand\tparbox[2]{\protect\parbox[t]{#1}{\protect\raggedright #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\subfigure[\tparbox{2.5cm}{caption for a}]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_a}%
}
~
\subfigure[\tparbox{2.5cm}{capture for b, justified}]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_b}%
}
~
\subfigure[\tparbox{2.5cm}{justification becomes ugly sometimes}]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_c}%
}
~
\subfigure[\tparbox{2.5cm}{there should be a way of applying \textbackslash raggedright or a similar command}]{
    \includegraphics[draft,width=3cm,height=3cm]{dummy}%
    \label{fig:myfig_d}%
}
\caption{Figure example}%
\label{fig:myfig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]