# Figures not appearing horizontally in two-columned latex journal

Tags: horizontal-alignment, alignment

I am using ACM two column template for a journal. Earlier when I used single column template I was able to show figures in full landscape, (2 rows and 4 columns) so 4 figures top and 4 figures bottom using the following code. Now moving to new template with 2-columns journal template, the same code renders all images vertically so all 8 images are stacked vertically in one of the text columns.

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable} % <---
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 1\label{sfig:a}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig1.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 2\label{sfig:b}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig2.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 3\label{sfig:c}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig3.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 4\label{sfig:d}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig4.png}}\\
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 5\label{sfig:e}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig5.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 6\label{sfig:f}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig6.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 7\label{sfig:g}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig7.png}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{Iteration 8\label{sfig:g}}{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth,height=2cm]{fig8.png}}\hfill
\caption{Captain of the figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

The following is the end result I want:

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513789/many-horizontal-images-in-two-column-latex-format--  an answer adapted from the link is pasted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigchi]{acmart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{author 1}
\begin{abstract}
The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the article.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
% <— this is important. There should be no empty line here. 
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
% <— this is important. There should be no empty line here. 
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. The images however appeared after References. Is is possible to have the images displayed in certain page or atleast before references?

Comment: will give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

- Your document class is unknown, so I use standard `article` with option `twocolumn`
- Added is formatting of subfigure captions with use of the `ragged2e` package
- Added is `stfloats` package, which enable to put figure on the bottom of the same page, if there is enough space for it. Positioning should be done manulaly with position option `[b]`

[image]

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[justification=RaggedRight]{subcaption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{author 1}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
The abstract is a short summary of the work to be presented in the article.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
    \begin{figure*}[b]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-b}
  \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
  \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.24\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \caption{The 1907 Franklin Model D roadster.}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Common caption}
    \end{figure*}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. It also solved positioning issue in my document!